# how to filter results from mysql inner join query

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many, inner-join

I have got a problem with my many to many relationship.

**Client table columns:**
clientID, name, address etc.

**User table columns:**
userID, name, address etc.

**Users_clients columns:**
userID, clientID.

Each client can have multible users attached and users can have multible clients.

Right now my `users_clients` table contains this:

```
userID | clientID<br>
1      | 2
1      | 3
2      | 2
2      | 3
3      | 3
3      | 2
4      | 1
```

On my php page I want a list of users which is not already attached to the client.

Ex. if I click on the client profile which has `clientID = 3`
It should show me a list of users not attached to this client.

```
SELECT u.name, u.email, u.userID FROM users u
  INNER JOIN users_clients uc
    ON u.userID = uc.userID 
  WHERE uc.clientID !=3
```

This works fine, but how do I create my MySQL query so that if a user have both clientID 3 and client 2 it doesn't show.

This query shows

1|2
2|2
3|2
4|1

and what I'm seeking is:

3|2
4|1

Hope this makes sense to you. Feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could process differently.

First make a request to seek every user with a clientId = 3;

```
select u.id from users u
INNER JOIN users_clients uc
ON u.userID = uc.userID 
WHERE uc.clientID =3;
```

And then you could use this request to fetch all the users except those who have a clientId = 3.

Final request looks like this :

```
select u.id from users u where u.id NOT IN (select u.id from users u
INNER JOIN users_clients uc
ON u.userID = uc.userID 
WHERE uc.clientID =3);
```

hope this'll help;

Comment: Thank you so much. This solved my qustion.
The query endend up looking like this:
SELECT u.userID, u.name, u.email FROM users u      
WHERE u.userID NOT IN (select u.userID from users u
INNER JOIN users_clients uc
ON u.userID = uc.userID
WHERE uc.clientID =:clientID

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a DISTINCT instruction ?

```
select distinct u.id from users u
INNER JOIN users_clients uc
ON u.userID = uc.userID 
WHERE uc.clientID =3;
```

Comment: if you want only the u.id you can reduce your request:  select uc.userID from  users_clients uc
WHERE uc.clientID =3;

Comment: This doesn't answer OP request